# Does anyone know why dgrid and dstore no longer seem to be available on unpkg?

Tags: dgrid, dstore, unpkg

I have been using unpkg to serve dgrid and dstore to my application for over a year and as of this morning it no longer seems to work.

I’ve tried using unpkg/dgrid/ and unpkg/dstore/ to get listings of the files in the packages with no success and even something like unpkg/react/ which usually works isn’t successful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe not an answer but as of September 2021, SitePen has migrated their code repositories to GitHub, and as a result, dgrid and dstore are no longer being actively maintained or developed.
It is possible that this migration has also affected the availability of these libraries on unpkg. However, it is important to note that unpkg is a community-supported CDN, which means that the availability of packages is dependent on whether they have been uploaded and maintained by members of the community.

Comment: I fixed this by directly loading both components into my application instead of using an external website to load them. It’s working fine now and thank you to Sebastian for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Why did you mention September 2021 even though you posted this in February 2023? Are you unaware that posting ChatGPT plagiarism is forbidden on Stack Overflow?